# How to reduce the CPU consumption of Olark's javascript-powered chat?

Tags: javascript, performance, cpu-usage

I just realized that removing [Olark](http://www.olark.com/) from my website reduced its CPU consumption from 20% to less than 1% (mesured with Google Chrome's process manager).

Do you know any way to reduce this CPU usage, while still providing the live chat/feedback functionality to users?

Comment: Use a different more efficient chat distribution. It also depends on Browser/OS combination. Older browsers take more CPU.

Comment: Hey there Adrien. This is Aaron from Olark. We left you a twitter message before, but I want to pop in here too, just in case--we've never seen this kind of process load from our widget, so we're really interested in helping track this down, shoot us an email at support@olark.com with whatever details you have and we'll see what we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Some javascript code optimisation should improve your situation. If Olark doesn't do (even after configuration/tweaking) what you require, you should check other solutions that provide the same service and check whether they perform better.

I don't think there's any better way...